# socket programming FD_ISSET() method usage

Tags: c, sockets, select

so I'm new to socket programming, and I was asked to write the server side that sends data to a client according to a certain request. I'm trying to server multiple clients at the same time. When a client first connects, the server accepts with no troubles whatsoever, but when a client sends a certain request, I get stuck in an infinity loop and it's not clear at all to me why the server keeps sending the same info to the client over and over and over again, below is my code for the server side:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#define MAX_CONNECTION 100
#ifndef max
    #define max(a,b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
#endif
typedef struct connection{
    char ipaddr[16];
    int port;
    int sd;
} connection;

static unsigned short SERVER_PORT = 4118;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int maxfd =-1;
    fd_set   rset, allset;
    connection client[MAX_CONNECTION];

    int passiveSock; /* Main Server Socket */
    struct sockaddr_in servSock_in;
#ifdef WIN32
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(0x0101, &wsaData);
#endif
    int port;
    if (argc > 1)
        port = atoi(argv[1]);
    else
        port = SERVER_PORT;

    for(int i=0; i < MAX_CONNECTION ; i++)
        client[i].sd = -1;
    memset((char *)&servSock_in, 0, sizeof(servSock_in));
    servSock_in.sin_family = PF_INET;
    servSock_in.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servSock_in.sin_port = htons((u_short)port);

    passiveSock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (passiveSock < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "I am too tired... I failed to open gate...\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (bind(passiveSock, (struct sockaddr *)&servSock_in, sizeof(servSock_in)) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "I couldn't attach gate to port...\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (listen(passiveSock, 5) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "I am not hearing anything...\n");
        return -1;
    }

    FD_SET(passiveSock, &allset);
        maxfd = max(maxfd, passiveSock);

        struct sockaddr_in cliSock_in;
        int cliSockLen;
        int connectedSock;
        cliSockLen = sizeof(cliSock_in);
        printf("\n Waiting for an incoming connection at port number %d", port);
        int bytesread = 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        //FD_ZERO(&allset);

        rset = allset;
        int nready = select(maxfd+1,&rset, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if(FD_ISSET(passiveSock, &rset)){
            printf("In the first if");

            connectedSock = accept(passiveSock, (struct sockaddr *)&cliSock_in, &cliSockLen);
            /* if an error occurs while accepting */
            if (connectedSock == -1)    {
                printf("\n Server: Accept error (errno = %d: %s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                continue;
            }




            for (int i=0; i<MAX_CONNECTION; i++)
                if (client[i].sd < 0){
                    client[i].sd=connectedSock;
                    strcpy(client[i].ipaddr, inet_ntoa(cliSock_in.sin_addr));
                    client[i].port= ntohs(cliSock_in.sin_port);
                    printf("\n Server: connection established with %s:%d\n", 
                        client[i].ipaddr, client[i].port);
                    break;
                }
            FD_SET(connectedSock, &allset);
            maxfd = max(maxfd, connectedSock);

        }

        else{
            for(int j = 0 ; j < MAX_CONNECTION; j++){
                connectedSock = client[j].sd;
                printf("connectedSock is %d", connectedSock);
                if(connectedSock < 0)
                    continue;
                if(FD_ISSET(client[j].sd, &rset)){
                    unsigned char buffer[66000];
                    int index = 0;
                    bytesread = recv(connectedSock, (char *)buffer, 66000, 0);
                    int  type;




                    type = (buffer[0] & 0xE0) >> 5;

                    if (type == 0)
                    {
                        char fname[100];
                        int i = 0;
                        int length = (buffer[i++] & 0x1F);
                        memcpy(&fname[0], &buffer[i], length);
                        fname[length] = '\0';
                        i += length;
                        int fs = 0;
                        fs += (buffer[i++] << 8) & 0xff00;
                        fs += buffer[i++];
                        char* filedata = (char*)malloc(fs*sizeof(char));
                        memcpy(&filedata[0], &buffer[i], fs);
                        filedata[fs] = '\0';
                        for (int i = 0; i < fs; i++)
                            printf("%c", filedata[i]);
                        printf("type=%d,length=%d,data=%s,fs=%d,filedata=%s", type, length, fname, fs, filedata);
                        std::ofstream of;
                        of.open(fname, std::ios::binary);
                        for (int i = 0; i < fs; i++)
                            of.write(filedata + i, 1);
                        of.close();
                        unsigned char rep;
                        int reptype = 0;
                        rep = (unsigned char)(reptype & 0x07);
                        send(connectedSock, (char*)(&rep), 1, 0);
                    }
                    else if (type == 1)
                    {
                        char fname[100];
                        int i = 0;
                        int length = (buffer[i++] & 0x1F);
                        memcpy(&fname[0], &buffer[i], length);
                        fname[length] = '\0';
                        i += length;
                        std::ifstream t;
                        int fs;
                        t.open(fname, std::ios::binary);
                        std::vector<char> vec((
                            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
                            (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));// open input file
                        t.close();
                        fs = vec.size();
                        char* filedata = (char*)malloc(fs*sizeof(char));    // allocate memory for a buffer of appropriate dimension
                        filedata = &vec[0];
                        filedata[fs] = '\0';
                        i = 0;
                        unsigned char* repbuffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(3 + length + fs);
                        repbuffer[i] = (unsigned char)(type & 0x07);
                        repbuffer[i] = repbuffer[i] << 5;
                        repbuffer[i] = repbuffer[i] | (length & 0x0000003F);
                        i++;
                        memcpy(&repbuffer[i], fname, length);
                        i = i + length;
                        printf("sizeof fs=%d", sizeof(fs));
                        repbuffer[i++] = (unsigned char)((fs & 0xff00) >> 8);
                        repbuffer[i++] = (unsigned char)(fs & 0xff);
                        memcpy(&repbuffer[i], filedata, fs);
                        printf("sizeof buffer=%d", sizeof(repbuffer));
                        i = i + fs;
                    //  printf("the buffer contains %s\n",&repbuffer[11]);
                        if (send(connectedSock, (char*)repbuffer, i, 0) == -1)
                        {
                            printf("A local error was detected while sending data! (errno = %d: %s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                            return -1;
                        }
                    }   
                    else if (type == 2)
                    {
                        char fname[100],nfname[100];
                        int i = 0;
                        int length = (buffer[i++] & 0x1F);
                        memcpy(&fname[0], &buffer[i], length);
                        fname[length] = '\0';
                        i += length;
                        int nlength = (buffer[i++] & 0x1F);
                        memcpy(&nfname[0], &buffer[i], nlength);
                        nfname[nlength] = '\0';
                        rename(fname,nfname);

                    }
                    else if (type == 3)
                    {
                        char rep[32];
                        strcpy(rep, "bye change get help put");
                        int length = strlen(rep);
                        unsigned char* repbuffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(1 + length);
                        int type = 6;
                        repbuffer[0] = (unsigned char)(type & 0x07);
                        repbuffer[0] = repbuffer[0] << 5;
                        repbuffer[0] = repbuffer[0] | (length & 0x0000003F);
                        memcpy(&repbuffer[1], rep, length);
                        if (send(connectedSock, (char*)repbuffer, length+1, 0) == -1)
                        {
                            perror("A local error was detected while sending data!!");
                            return -1;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (type == 4)
                    {
                        closesocket(connectedSock);
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    closesocket(passiveSock);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;

}
```

I feel there's something wrong with the usage of FD_ISSET() method, I've been trying to figure out the error for 2 hours now, pleeassse help

Comment: This is not a site where you get to dump a large chunk of code, and ask someone else to find your bugs for you. You need to be able to demonstrate your problem in the minimum amount of code that reproduces it, no more than a page or two. Having said that, I do not see where you're initializing the file descriptor masks with FD_ZERO. Your "allset" fd_set likely contains random garbage, which gets passed to select(). There could be other problems too; this is too large of a code chunk to review, at once.

Comment: You aren't checking the return value of select (nor recv, nor send), which is likely failing due to invalid fd's in the set.  I agree with @SamVarshavchik that you need to initialize your allset using FD_ZERO at the beginning of the program (not inside the loop).

Comment: when you've been trying for 2 hours to find a bug in the code and you've already been awake for 26 hours doing other stuff I don't think you would care for being specific in your question.... second, I've seen people here posting much larger chunks of code, third, this isn't a school, I have enough professors and doctors who take rules too seriously and I don't need another one. fourth, your advice didn't work, but thanks anyways

Comment: there are a few problems with the logic of the code.  in general, if the accept() fails, then the code is in an infinite loop  if the accept() succeeds, the code never gets into the processing of the connection rather it goes into the same 'for(;;;)' loop

Comment: @samsmith Your scheduling problems are your own but you would certainly be better off in bed than bashing away at anything for 26 hours straight. Over a long career I have frequently found that problems that baffled me the day before were solved while shaving in the morning.

Comment: EJP I don't need your advice either ;)

Comment: If you, apparently, don't need anyone's advice and assistance, then why are you here? And, as I suspected, and someone else pointed out, you have multiple bugs in your code. It's not going to work until you fix them all. That's how it works.

Comment: *insert nicholas cage you don't say face here*